# How to format a removable device (flash drive) with int 13h in 16-bit MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm, hard-drive

Does anybody remember how to use int 13h service 5 to format a hard disk or removable device? I just need a example of how do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are facing two problems:

Flash drives and hard disks are typically not formatted in the way floppy disks are (were) formatted. Floppy disks had to be formatted to create sectors and tracks on an unstructured "magnetic" surface.

This kind of formatting is called low-level formatting (INT 13h, AH=5 or AH=6).

Flash devices are never formatted this way because they do not have an unstructured "magnetic" surface.

Modern hard disks (everything that came after ESDI technology in 1980s) are formatted in the factory and there is no standardized or documented way how to do re-format these disks at home. The INT 13h functions for formatting a hard disk will typically not work with IDE, SCSI or SATA hard disks.

What is done when "formatting an USB drive" is nothing but simply writing sectors (INT 13h, AH=3 or AH=43h) to the disk that does not contain file system information, yet, or overwriting existing file system information.

The second problem you are facing is that most BIOSs do not manage USB storage devices.

If you boot from an USB device using such a BIOS you can read this device (and only this one) using INT 13h, AH=2 or AH=42h. Maybe you can also write the device (AH=3 or AH=43h). However you are not really trying to format the device you are booting from?

Comment: No, i'll format using the Windows XP. Writing a .com Assembly to do that.

Comment: Under Windows XP? I thaught that Windows XP does not allow direct disk access (int 013h) for DOS programs! Anyway: Formatting an USB drive is nothing but writing sectors to the drive (unless you use an 3.5" USB floppy drive).